# Can there be interactions which destroy/create a single Fermion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, interactions

Consider a process of fundamental particles $f\rightarrow x,y$, where $x$ and $y$ are fundamental (no composites of fermions) bosonic particles.
Can such a process exist? I know that e.g. Majorana Fermions are not charged, but still they are Fermions and can only react to other Fermions.
An obstacle to such a process would be of course angular momentum, but can there be also half-integer angular momentum?
So could we write an interaction of the form $\Delta\mathcal{L} =g\bar{\psi}\theta\Phi^2+ h.c.$, where $\psi$ is a fermion $\theta$ a Grassman variable and $\Phi$ a scalar. Of course the matrix element would be Grassman-valued, but still the absolute value squared would still be a regular number if we choose a matrix representation for $\theta$.
Could this be a valid interaction or are there other reasons why it must not exist (e.g. Pauli exclusion principle, unitarity, etc.)?

Comment: How would you ensure Lorentz invariance if you have only one fermion?

Comment: The symmetry $(-1)^f$ is unbreakable in any quantum system of fermions.